# Is it possible Custom theme for desktop and Luma theme for mobile and ipad

Tags: magento-2.1, mobile, parent-child-theme, luma-theme

Is it possible to use blank or luma theme for mobile and custom theme for desktop in magento2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by design configuration from magento 2 admin.

Go to **STORES > Configuration > General > Design -> User-Agent Exceptions**

**Search String  ->** Search strings are either normal strings or regular exceptions (PCRE).

**For example :** iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera Mini

**Design Theme :** Select the theme you want to load.

You can also use screen resolution regular expressions for loading theme based on resolutions.